# How to test the android app language changed or not?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

1. In my android app, I have 3 options for language selection.i.e; Hindi,English,French
2. Programmatically changed default language(English) to Hindi.
3. How to verify whether app language changed to Hindi or not.(programmatically)

please help

Comment: get some string from resources, and compare it to the Hindi translation in the code

Answer (score 0):

To check whether language changed or not there may be many ways to verify but simply you can assert page title or that drop down text with expected text.

Answer (score 0):

When the language is changed, take the reference of any text or tile or any element placeholder or label, and verify the string by using equalsIgnoreCase("") method.

Comment: please explain me step by step

Comment: Let's say There is some text on the page as "Register" which will become "Whatever Hindi" after language change, now driver.findElement(By.xpath(0)).getText(); Compare it with the expected text by using text.equalsIgnoreCase("your expected text") use an if condition for assertion